# Bootstrap show info based on id in modal

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show more info about the file from the database using modal instead adding more columns to the table, and also instead of opening new page.
here is my code

```
<table id="file" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
     <?php
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM files") 
     ?>
    <thead>
      <tr>
      <th>ID <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
      <th>Name <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
      <th>Size <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
      <th>Delete </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php        
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
     ?>
       <tr class="record">
        <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo  $row['name']; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo  $row['size']; ?> </td>
    <td><div align="center"><a href="#" id="<?php echo  $row['id'] ?>" class="infobutton fa fa-times" title="Info"></a></div></td>
        <td><div align="center"><a href="#" id="<?php echo  $row['id'] ?>" class="delbutton fa fa-times" title="Click To Delete"></a></div></td>
       </tr>

     <?php
     } 
     ?>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance.
If there any other way place say it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the following data-target and modal ID with PHP, if that is what you mean.

```
    <!--This calls the modal by data-target ID -->
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">This link calls the modal</a>


    <!--modal content-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"></h4>
    </div>
  <div class="modal-body">

<!--  your content goes here  -->

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <center><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button></center>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But I think there will be a lot of codes especially when I am having more than 1000 rows!

Comment: You can put as much content as you like into a modal, they can have a side scroll bar.

Comment: No, When I use this code it will be replicated with the number of the records I have, So I think the page will load very slowly

Comment: I think you need to decide how many rows to load at one time.  Maybe look at some other UX methods.  Like loading content when user scrolls to the bottom.